# Passing a variable to an angular 1.x component that is in a Angular Material Dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angular-material

I am trying to pass an object to a component that is inside an angular material dialog.

The function I use to display the Dialog is:

```
    ctrl.openCampaignSplitDialog = function(ev, split){
        $mdDialog.show({
            template: '<campaign-split-dialog split="$ctrl.split"></campaign-split-dialog>',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        }).then(function(split) {
                ctrl.addCampaignSplit(split);
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
            });
    };
```

This correctly opens up the dialog.

This is the code for the component:

```
angular
.module('app')
.component('campaignSplitDialog', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/campaignSplitDialog/campaignSplitDialog.html',
    controller: campaignSplitDialogCntrlr,
    bindings:{
        split: '<'
    }
});

/** @ngInject */
function campaignSplitDialogCntrlr($mdDialog) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('splitter', ctrl.split);
}
```

The issue arrises from the fact I am not sure how to pass in the `split` object from the open dialog function to the component module. In the 'template' URL there I have `split="$ctrl.split"`.  I have tried multiple different ways but none worked.  I have tried double brackets, plain variable name, and using the controllerAs syntax.

I have also tried passing the value in through the dialog by using the `locals:{}` paramter but because I do not specify a controller, since it is configured when the component is called upon, it does not appear in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the first line of your question - "I am trying to pass an object to a component that is inside an angular material dialog" - as the way you are trying to achieve it doesn't look correct.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QGGvvK?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="app">
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.open($event)">
    Custom Dialog
  </md-button>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Test">
        <campaign-split split="text"></campaign-split>
    </md-dialog>
  </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial'])

.component('campaignSplit', {
    template: '<div>{{$ctrl.split}}</div>',
    bindings:{
        split: '<'
    }
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  this.open = function(ev) {
    $scope.text = "Hello";
    $mdDialog.show(
      {
        templateUrl: "test.html",
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        scope: $scope,
        preserveScope: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
       },
    });
  };

  this.save = function () {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  }
})
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check the property options.**locals** https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/#mddialog-show-optionsorpreset

```
$mdDialog.show({
        template: '<campaign-split-dialog split="$ctrl.split"></campaign-split-dialog>',
        locals:{
             split: $ctrl.split
        },
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints. 

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently are doing it, is skipping the dialogs controller.

In this scenario there are three controllers.

1) state controller
2 dialog controller
3) component controller

The proper way to do this is:

```
ctrl.openCampaignSplitDialog = function(ev, split){
        $mdDialog.show({
            template: '<campaign-split-dialog split="split"></campaign-split-dialog>',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            locals: {split: $ctrl.split}
            controller: function($scope, split){
             $scope.split = split;
            },
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        }).then(function(split) {
                ctrl.addCampaignSplit(split);
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
            });
    };
```

This is the code for the component:

```
angular
.module('app')
.component('campaignSplitDialog', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/campaignSplitDialog/campaignSplitDialog.html',
    controller: campaignSplitDialogCntrlr,
    bindings:{
        split: '<'
    }
});

/** @ngInject */
function campaignSplitDialogCntrlr($mdDialog) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('splitter', ctrl.split);
}
```

So what is happening is, the variable `$ctrl.split` is going from the state controller to the dialog controller using `locals`, then in the dialog controller, you bind it to `$scope`, then from there you can pass the variable `$scope.split` to the component tag, that passes the variable to the component `bindings`